# How do I merge "git stash pop" conflict by using Git Bash?

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a `foo.cpp` file. There is a modification on master branch,

```
merge conflict test, make a master modification.
```

There is another modification on the branch br1 in the same line,

```
merge conflict test, make a local modification and will stash it.
```

Now, I'm on br1 and stash the local modification, then I rebase the master branch.

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Then I `git stash pop` the local modification, here I get the conflict,

```
<<<<<<< Updated upstream
merge conflict test, make a master modification.
=======
merge conflict test, make a local modification and will stash it.
>>>>>>> Stashed changes
```

Here's the problem. When I working on Visual Studio, I know I can click "merge" button within the VS GUI to edit the conflict. After that, I can `git --continue` to go through this conflict.

But in current situation, I don't have VS. I don't how the command to edit the conflict. I can edit it in notepad, because the conflict is simple, but I don't know how to mark it as resolved.

Comment: You have to use `git add <path_to_file>` to add it to the index. That marks the conflict as resolved and you can use `git merge --continue` to continue the merge.

Comment: @kowsky, I have looked up this too. `git add <path_to_file>` can work, but `git merge --continue` turned out error: unknown option `continue'

Comment: If you don't have `git merge --continue`, your Git is fairly old (run `git --version` to get its version number). All `git merge --continue` does, though, is verify that there is a merge to finish, then run `git commit`—so you can just run `git commit` since you don't have the `--continue` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have popped the stash you can run `git status` to get information on some actions you can perform to go forward. After you have resolved the conflicts you can add the file to mark the conflict as resolved:

```
$ git checkout master
$ <make changes to file>
$ git add file
$ git commit -m "on master, make some changes to file"
$ git checkout -b b1 HEAD~
$ <make local changes to file>
$ git stash
$ git rebase master
$ git status
  On branch b1
  Unmerged paths:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
     (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

           both modified:   file

  no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ <edit file to resolve conflicts>
$ git add file
$ git reset
```

The `git reset` will unstage all changes made to the file. It's not necessary to resolve the conflicts, but it will set you back to a state similar to the one you had before the stash and rebase.